# Rails: How can I query Rooms of a specific Hotel model for example? What the REST URL/controller specifics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord, model

I'm a beginner at Ruby on Rails, I've only been looking at it for the month of April, trying to create a backend Rails API for an iOS app.

I've created a very simple backend model to help me learn. Hotel Room Visit and Layout are my 4 models.

Right I have some seed data in the DB, and I have Hotel and Room responding with json data.

/hotels.json returns a json list of all my hotels. /rooms.json does the same thing for rooms.

/hotels/3.json returns json data for the hotel with id 3. /rooms/3.json does the same thing for the room with id 3.

I've built an iOS app that read this data in and displays it.

What I'm wondering is...

How do I get all the Rooms for a Hotel with a specific hotel_id? By that I mean the URL/parameters. I'm a completely noob remember so I know very little about any of this other than what I've learned up to this point. What URL do I need? In my Room model I have a method defined as follows...

```
def self.rooms_with_hotel_id(hotel_id)
  self.where(hotel_id: hotel_id)
end
```

But what URL do I need to access to get such a json response?

I've set up index & show in my rooms_controller and hotels_controller. However, I don't quite understand how to make the connection for rooms of specific hotel. Would /hotels/3/room.json make sense? If so, how do I set that up in my controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to put method in your rooms_controller like this

```
def anymethodname
  @rooms = Rooms.where(hotel_id: params[:hotel_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @rooms }
  end
end
```

so when you visit this url --> yourdomain.name/rooms/anymethodname?hotel_id=12 will get you all the rooms with hotel_id = 12 in json format